# What's the lattice dimension of the uSVP for attacking CRYSTALS-Dilithium-128?

Tags: lattice-crypto, nist

I am trying to understand the process of transitioning from a NIST standard to the attacks based on of the Unique Shortest Vector Problem (Unique-SVP). Specifically, I am working with Crystals Dilithium 2 and would like to understand how to obtain the lattice dimension associated to the uSVP.

For example in Crystals Dilithium 2 we have:

- Public key size: 1312
- Private key size: 2528
- Security level: 128-bit

I'm familiar with Kannan's Embedding, but I'm unsure about the dimension of the Learning With Errors (LWE) problem on which Dilithium operates.